# Insert but Don't Commit MySql

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-commit

I am pretty new to MySql and Databases, and I was wondering in python sometimes I forgot to commit after an insert, and then when I do then next insert and commit that one the, auto-incrementing `id` column has skipped a number.

So I was wondering what happens when you insert and forget to commit is this bad for the Database? Or does is just skip because when you insert it assigned an id to it but didn't save it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A skipped id can happen in several situation.  Keep in mind that an `INSERT` generally starts by allocating all the ids that it *may* need.  Here's a few examples where `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids are 'burned':

```
BEGIN; INSERT; ROLLBACK;

INSERT IGNORE -- and some of them are ignored due to dup key

REPLACE -- DELETE, then INSERT
```

The one I dislike is:

```
SET autocommit = 0;
INSERT
forget to ever do the COMMIT
```

For that reason, I avoid autocommit=0.

In a multi-master (including Galera) setup, with `auto_increment_increment` > 1, the `INSERTs` on one master skip values.

Comment: great thanks for reply, but is it bad when an id is skipped?

Comment: @spenf10 no, it is not. Unless you need unbroken series (for accounting etc) and in that case you should not use auto_increment for that.

Comment: Another _potential_ 'badness' in burning ids is when you burn them so fast that the integers threaten to overflow.  Once I got in trouble with `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (65K max) and "I'll never need more than a few thousand".  But the code was burning ids.